# Не работает реактивность vue js

Tags: vue.js

```
<div class="course_add_block_detail">
  <VueEditor :placeholder="$t('short_course_desc_en')" v-model="course" />
</div>

 <script>
import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor'

export default {
  name: 'CourseEdit',
  components: {
    VueEditor
  },
  data () {
    return {
      course: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async get () {
      await this.$store.dispatch('getCourseData', this.$route.params.courseId)
        .then((response) => {
          this.course = response.data[0]
          console.log(this.course)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.error = err.response.data.message
        })
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.get()
  }
}
</script>
```

Не работает реактивность. После загрузки значение переменной course не меняется. Из базы данных приходят данные, и console.log(this.course) показывает, что this.course принимает эти данные. Однако при рендеринге переменный course пустой. Можете подсказать в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проверьте, что ```this``` в this.course - правильный.